# Does Service Fabric keep actor information indefinitely?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

For GDPR reasons, I need to ensure that I don't store customer data which I no longer need. When looking at Service Fabric Actors, I am uncertain what "garbage collection" really means.

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
internal class Actor1 : Actor, IActor1
{
    public Actor1(ActorService actorService, ActorId actorId) 
        : base(actorService, actorId)
    {
    }

    public Task PingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
IActorService actorServiceProxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(
    new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyActorService"), partitionKey);
// ...
do
{
    PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await actorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);
// ...
```

When enumerating [actor instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-enumerate) in a test environment, it seemed to me like actor information was kept for at least 2 months, even though the actors did not have any stored state.

I found multiple articles mentioning that I will need to delete the actors manually if they have leftover state, but in my case the only "state" would be the fact that the actorId "exists". If I were to use something sensitive like a user email address as an actorId, would Service Fabric ever delete the information about the actorId by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garbage collection (in this context) means that an Actor object is removed from memory to free up resources. If the Actor has `StatePersistence.Persisted` its state will be written to disk on each replica of the underlying `ActorService`. Even if you're not explicitly storing anything in the `StateManager`, a record of the Actor (using `ActorId` as key) will exist.

It's up to you as a developer to manage the lifecycle of Actor state. Deleting an Actor explicitly, also deletes its state.

> Garbage collection of deactivated actors only cleans up the actor
> object, but it does not remove data that is stored in an actor's State
> Manager. When an actor is reactivated, its data is again made
> available to it through the State Manager. In cases where actors store
> data in State Manager and are deactivated but never reactivated, it
> may be necessary to clean up their data.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-delete-actors).

Comment: In other words, just having `StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)` means it will create a bit of state about the fact that the actor exists/existed. Therefore, I need to delete it as well if I want it gone. Or use a different value for the attribute. Thanks